# Using the same values in separate if statements in java

Tags: java

I am working on a problem where I have a menu option 1. to shuffle the word, 2 to take the shuffle word and try to fix it by changing the array index numbers.

I did this part `if (input==1)` shuffle the word.

I now have to take that the same shuffle word in in `if (input==2)` section and try to fix it. Can anybody guide me how can I use the same values in this block `if(input==1)`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Select an item from below: \n");
            System.out.println("(1) Mix");
            System.out.println("(2) Solve");
            System.out.println("(3) Quit");

            int input;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            input = scan.nextInt();

            String team;
            String mix_word;
            char orig_team[];
            char mix_team[];
            boolean Result;
            // System.out.println(input);
            if (input == 1) {
                team = orig();
                System.out.println(team);

                mix_word = mix(team);
                System.out.println(mix_word);

                orig_team = team.toCharArray();
                mix_team = mix_word.toCharArray();
                int arg_length = mix_team.length;

            }
            if (input == 2) {

            }
            if (input == 3) {
                break;
            }

            if (input > 3 || input <= 0) {

                System.out.println("input accurate numbers 1 or 2 or 3");
            }
        }
    }

    static String mix(String Team) {
        String word = shuffle(Team);
        return word;
    }

    static String shuffle(String input) {
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            characters.add(c);
        }

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
        while (characters.size() != 0) {
            int randPicker = (int) (Math.random() * characters.size());
            output.append(characters.remove(randPicker));
        }

        return output.toString();
    }

    static String orig()

    {
        String[] lines = new String[1000];// Enough lines.
        int counter = 0;
        try {
            File file = new File("input.txt");// The path of the File
            FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);
            boolean flag = true;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    lines[counter] = buffer.readLine();// Store a line in the
                                                        // array.
                    if (lines[counter] == null) {// If there isn't any more
                                                    // lines.
                        buffer.close();
                        fileReader1.close();
                        break;// Stop reading and close the readers.

                    }
                    counter++;

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception ocurred.");
        }

        int pick;
        Random rand = new Random();
        pick = rand.nextInt(counter) + 0;
        return (lines[pick]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a `switch` statement

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I am using switch statement, still having issues. I get different values for the same variable in two blocks. It needs to be the same.

Comment: My guess is you haven't placed a `break;` between case statements.  If you forget to do this, it will run from one case to another.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Did you possibly overlook the little `while(true)` at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather pathological use case of the `switch` statement but you can take advantage of the drop-through and do the following:

```
switch(input) {
case 1:
    team = orig();
    System.out.println(team);

    mix_word = mix(team);
    System.out.println(mix_word);

    orig_team = team.toCharArray();
    mix_team = mix_word.toCharArray();
    arg_length = mix_team.length;

    // No break; here!
case 2:
    //  do the rest of your thing as if it were case 2
    break;
case 3:
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("input accurate numbers 1 or 2 or 3");
}
```

Comment: I did this switch statement. In case number 2, I need to be able to use the same values as in case1. when I put 2, values changes.

Comment: I did this and in case 2, I have this: System.out.println(mix_word); I get this error:javac Project2.java
Project2.java:41: variable mix_word might not have been initialized
          System.out.println(mix_word);

Comment: just initialize mix_word to some default value in case you are in `case 3`.

Answer (score 2):

In every loop cycle (which handles a **single** user input) you declare your variables, so their scope (the access range) is limited to that cycle.

If you declare your variables outside the while-loop, their scope will stretch over the whole loop (until the end of the method):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String team = "";
    String mix_word = "";
    char orig_team[] = null;
    char mix_team[] = null;
    boolean Result = false;
    while (true) {
        // ** your usual input handling here **
    }
}
```

Also be sure to initialize them (e.g. with a default value), or else the program will not compile.

Another way would be to create member- or class-variables, which would have the advantage of automatic initialization and a larger scope.